# How can I disable usb charging on Android phone (Nexus 5)

Tags: charging

I use my Nexus 5 as development device, so I plug-in and plug-out into computer usb very often.
What makes me worried is that too many this way "li-on" battery charging cycles get wasted too fast.

My Nexus 5 is rooted.
I want it to charge only when connected to wall socket.

I saw there are similar questions but I haven't found any concrete solution yet.
Apart "sync only cable". but does it really exists?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is possible in theory, but I've yet to use any app that actually works. How about leaving it plugged out altogether and use something like AirDroid to transfer things between your computer and the phone? For this to properly work you would need a customised Kernel that supports this feature. A custom kernel would be device specific so you would need a Nexus 5 kernel with no USB charging. I've yet to find one and I think you need a different solution to this. I will keep looking though! You could try https://github.com/t0mm13b/USBChargeCommander/blob/master/README but I haven't seen it work

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about battery. There is nothing like fixed cycle count counter. Plugging it very often is actually better than cycling it 10%->100%->10%->100%.

Comment: Could you point to some documentation to support this?